# Supports and raft hard to remove Up Mini Printer

Tags: support-structures, rafts

I have an Up mini printer and the raft and supports are often really hard/seemingly impossible to remove from the model. I read that this could be because the Up prints at high temperatures, however, I adjusted according to the recommended value for my filament (ABS). I have tried the highs and lows of the recommended settings and still haven’t had much luck. I have also tried adjusting the distance between the nozzle and print bed. I would appreciate some help, especially from people with Up Minis. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Does ["Difficult to remove support material"](/q/7989) answer your question?

Comment: Try using a skirt instead of a raft. In my opinion, a raft is annoying because it always sticks to the model. Skirts are so much better! Also, get a magnetic removable print bed, like a Ziflex. I have one of those and once you have leveled your bed correctly they are amazing. Prints stick well to them and you simply 'flex' the plate and the model pops right off. About the supports, it might depend on what brand of ABS you are using..?

Comment: Also look in [this answer](/a/11721); it describes how to insert more distance between the product and the support, this is also possible for the raft.

Comment: @RosalieW did you mean a brim? Because a skirt normally does not even touch the actual model.

Comment: I personally use a skirt, just because it makes the model easier to remove from the build plate (indeed because it does not actually touch the model). Also, it eliminates the task of having to cut the brim/raft away from the model. Here is a nice link contrasting a raft vs a brim vs a skirt: https://all3dp.com/2/3d-printing-raft-brim-and-skirt-all-you-need-to-know/ Then you can decide what you want to use

Comment: @RosalieW It isn't always a matter of choice, some models and printing materials **require** a brim to grip better to the surface without having a dislodged print. A raft may sometimes be necessary, e.g. when printing high temperature, prone to warping co-polymers or ABS. But this discussion is getting off topic. As far as I'm concerned, this is a duplicate question, we let the community decide.